# Portion of a formula in another cell

Tags: excel

i will try to be a simple as possible to explain this.

Is it possible to have a portion of a formula in another cell, lets say cell B1 containing a portion and cell A1 containing the complete formula which it references the value of A1 within

I am trying to do this without using macros.

For example,

If `A1` contains the formula:

```
= AVERAGE(IF( (($B$1:$B$7 = "Jan")+($B$1:$B$7 = "Feb"))*($C$1:$C$7=2013),$A$1:$A$7,""))
```

Then the `B1` value where I want to have the portion of the formula should be

```
= ($B$1:$B$7 = "Jan")+($B$1:$B$7 = "Feb")
```

I have tried the following:

```
A1 = AVERAGE(IF( (($B$2)*($C$1:$C$7=2013),$A$1:$A$7,""))
```

However, this does not work. Is there any way to do this?

I also tried double-quotes for the value in `B1` and that didn't work either.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're asking. Can you give us some examples of *actual text* that might result from these formulas? In other words, the result values in addition to the formulas themselves? I don't really see what `($B$1:$B$7 = "Jan")` is meant to represent.